# Xamarin 9 patch image not scaling properly

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, nine-patch

I am trying to use a 9 patch image as the background for a label.  My image has two rounded corners and I want to keep the rounding radius the same, regardless of any stretching.

I am using a RelativeLayout to position the background image behind the foreground label.  I want to stretch the background image to the height and width of the RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout Padding="15">
    <Image Aspect="Fill" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" Source="panel_header" />
    <Label Margin="15" Text="{ Binding CategoryTitle }" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The image is stretching to fill the width and height of the parent layout in the Android emulator, however, it is not honouring the 9 patch constraints - it is distorting the whole image as it would for a standard image.

My 9 patch images can be found [here](http://www.flashcardsmate.com/panel_header.9.zip).  Am I missing something?

Comment: Your 9P images are fine, Xamarin.Forms programmatically creates the layouts and they do not use Android's NinePatch (or alternatives) to scale the image. They of course work in a non-Forms Xamarin.Android project. There are commercial alternatives for 9P image usage in Xamarin.Forms such as: Forms9Patch.com

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks for that.